# How to consolidate information from Sheet1 (supplier) to master Sheet1 and Sheet2 (supplier) to MasterSheet2

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with VBA (macros for Excel)

While trying to Copy `SupplierFile1,File2(sheet2)` to `Masterfile(Sheet2)`

After using Dir to access the supplier file and copying the data from sheet2 I am doing this

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
erow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(erow, 1), 

Cells(erow, 5)) //"This part is showing error"
```

I am not a programmer and tried the solutions available online and YouTube but nothing is working.

Comment: what error is showing? You forgot to mention that.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with:

```
Cells(erow, 5)) //"This part is showing error"
```

but you have one too many parenthesis. It should be

```
Cells(erow, 5) 'Something else needs to go here
```

Try something like this

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Range(.Cells(erow, 5).Select  'or whatever you're wanting to do
End With
```